# Is there a concept of neural networks that edit neural networks?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I think that neural networks can edit their own neural networks, and if we combine them with evolutionary algorithms, we can make a strong artificial intelligence.

Is there a concept of neural network editing itself? Neural networks can edit themselves.

Comment: This question is not pertinent to this forum

Comment: We already have a good way to change network weights called "Gradient Descent". No need to use a neural network that changes the weight of another network. And if you want to apply "Evolutionary Algorithms" why not use it with network1 instead of using it in network2 that edits network1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to ai.stackexchange.com (artificial intelligence stack exchange).

Comment: @Andreas Rau Because Network 1 does not have editing ability. A network with the ability to edit other networks is another evolutionary algorithm that evolutionism has produced.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's really no point to this. Gradient descent is already a very good optimizer. There is something like this, called AutoML though, that basically uses another neural network to edit a neural network's hyperparameters...
2. If a neural network's only input was it's own weights, then how does it know that the error of the neural network is supposed to go down, then?